# C++: passing the template callback method into the other method: cannot convert ‘<unresolved overloaded function type> to pointer

Tags: c++, templates, callback

I have a container that stores the structures that contain the template callback.
At the same time callbacks signature does not contain template parameters.
When inserting into it, I get the error:

`cannot convert ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘smb1_subdecoder::send_subflow_premature_end_msg_t’  {aka ‘void (smb1_subdecoder::*)(long unsigned int, unsigned char, long unsigned int, unsigned char)’}`

```
note:   initializing argument 4 of  
‘void smb1_subdecoder::store_subflow_bunch_on_open(
    smb1_subdecoder::handle_t, uint64_t, CIFS_RESOURCE_TYPE, 
    smb1_subdecoder::send_subflow_premature_end_msg_t, 
    smb1_subdecoder::send_subflow_premature_end_msg_t)’
    send_subflow_premature_end_msg_t send_subflow_premature_end_rq_msg,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
```

**Insert code (Error here):**

```
store_subflow_bunch_on_open(
    handle(response_msg.file_id), response_msg.msg_id, 
    static_cast<CIFS_RESOURCE_TYPE>(parm_open2_rsp->resource_type),
    &send_subflow_premature_end_msg<ntdec_cifs_close_request>,
    &send_subflow_premature_end_msg<ntdec_cifs_close_response>);
```

**Defines:**

Store method:

```
void smb1_subdecoder::store_subflow_bunch_on_open(
    handle_t handle, uint64_t subflow_msg_id, CIFS_RESOURCE_TYPE resource_type,
    send_subflow_premature_end_msg_t send_subflow_premature_end_rq_msg,
    send_subflow_premature_end_msg_t send_subflow_premature_end_rsp_msg) { ... }
```

send_subflow_premature_end_msg_t:

```
typedef void (smb1_subdecoder::*send_subflow_premature_end_msg_t)
                    (uint64_t, uint8_t, uint64_t, uint8_t);
```

template function for send premature end msg (the signature does not depend on the template parameter as described above):

```
template<class NTDEC_END_OBJECT_T>
void smb1_subdecoder::send_subflow_premature_end_msg(uint64_t subflow_msg_id, uint8_t close_reason,
                                                     uint64_t header_msg_id, uint8_t side)
{
    NTDEC_END_OBJECT_T end_msg;
    _d_smb->proto_fill(end_msg, subflow_msg_id);
    end_msg.header_msg_id = header_msg_id;
    if (_d_smb->transport() == decoder_smb::TRANSPORT::NETBIOS)
    {
        const auto* netbios_msg = _d_smb->get_proto_parent<ntdec_object>();
        if (netbios_msg)
            set_parent_msg_id(end_msg, netbios_msg->msg_id);
    }
    end_msg.side = (side == -1) ? _d_smb->get_last_data_side() : side;

    _d_smb->stream().send_message(end_msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must qualify the name of a non-static member with the class name explicitly when [constructing a pointer to member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator).

(emphasis mine)

> 2. If the operand is a qualified name of a non-static member, e.g.
>    `&C::member`, the result is a prvalue pointer to member function or
>    pointer to data member of type T in class C. **Note that neither `&member`
>    nor `C::member` nor even `&(C::member)` may be used to initialize a
>    pointer to member**.

E.g.

```
store_subflow_bunch_on_open(
    handle(response_msg.file_id), response_msg.msg_id, 
    static_cast<CIFS_RESOURCE_TYPE>(parm_open2_rsp->resource_type),
    &smb1_subdecoder::send_subflow_premature_end_msg<ntdec_cifs_close_request>,
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    &smb1_subdecoder::send_subflow_premature_end_msg<ntdec_cifs_close_response>);
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```